# reset password not working, error : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I am trying to make a function for reset password. I'm using react.js v17.

I am using "temp mail" for emailing purpose, verification email is being received successfully but unfortunately reset password is not working.

This is the error I have:

```
bundle.js:735 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Module.auth (bundle.js:841:32)
    at sendPasswordResetEmail (bundle.js:730:84)
    at sendPasswordResetEmail (bundle.js:730:13)
    at sendPasswordResetEmail (bundle.js:730:13)
    at sendPasswordResetEmail (bundle.js:730:13)
```

This is my code in js file

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  `import "./Forgottenpass.css";
            import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
            import { sendPasswordResetEmail } from "firebase/compat/auth";
            import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
            import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
            import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
            import { auth } from "../../firebase/firebase";
        
            function Forgottenpass() {
              const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
              const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
              const navigate = useNavigate();
        
              useEffect(() => {
                if (loading) return;
                // if (user) navigate("/home");
              }, [user, loading]);
        
              // PASSWORD REST
              const resetForgottenPass = async (email) => {
                 if (email !== "") {
                   try {
                     await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth.currentUser, email);
                     console.log(email, "email");
                     console.log(auth, "auth");
                     alert("Password reset link sent on your given Email!");
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    alert(error.message);
                  }
              } else {
                 alert("Please enter your email address.");
    }
};
        
              return (
                <div className="forgottenpass">
                  <div className="forgottenpass-container">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="forgottenpass-textBox"
                      value={email}
                      onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                      placeholder="E-mail Address"
                    />
                    <button
                      className="forgottenpass-btn"
                      onClick={resetForgottenPass}
                    >
                      Send password reset email
                    </button>
                    <div>
                      Don 't have an account? <Link to="/register">Register</Link> now.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            }
            export default Forgottenpass;
            `
```

Comment: You're setting function name `sendPasswordResetEmail`  same as Firebase auth function. change the name of rhe password reset function

Comment: I have update the chances above also, please help with the error 
i changed that in my code too.. but still not working. facing a new error, 

"Firebase: The continue URL provided in the request is invalid. (auth/invalid-continue-uri)."

Answer (score 0):

You name `sendPasswordResetEmail` twice. You have imported function `sendPasswordResetEmail` and you define handle in `Forgottenpass` with name `sendPasswordResetEmail`

[image]

Rename function in you component and everything will be okey.

Comment: I have changed that too.. but still not working.
facing a new error, "Firebase: The continue URL provided in the request is invalid. (auth/invalid-continue-uri)."

Comment: Okey but this is another error..